# Return type in wsimport-generated service stub methods

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

Here is an example of wsimport-generated service stub method:

```
    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetSynonym", action = "GetSynonymRequest")
    @WebResult(name = "Synonyms", targetNamespace = "service.bnsf.com/contact/ContactMessages")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "GetSynonym", targetNamespace = "service.bnsf.com/contact/ContactMessages", className = "com.bnsf.service.contact.contactmessages.GetSynonymRequest")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "GetSynonymResponse", targetNamespace = "service.bnsf.com/contact/ContactMessages", className = "com.bnsf.service.contact.contactmessages.GetSynonymResponse")
    public Synonyms getSynonym(
            @WebParam(name = "RequestContext", targetNamespace = "service.bnsf.com/contact/ContactMessages") RequestContext requestContext,
            @WebParam(name = "SynonymId", targetNamespace = "service.bnsf.com/contact/ContactMessages") EntityId synonymId)
            throws BusinessFaultMessage, ServiceFaultMessage;
```

Note that return type is Synonyms class.

Here are the relevant wsdl parts:

```
<xs:element name="GetSynonymResponse" type="GetSynonymResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="GetSynonymResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Synonyms" type="account:Synonyms"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
...
<wsdl:message name="GetSynonymResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="msg:GetSynonymResponse" name="GetSynonymResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
...
<wsdl:operation name="GetSynonym">
    <soap:operation soapAction="GetSynonymRequest" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input name="GetSynonymRequestRequest">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="GetSynonymRequestResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    <wsdl:fault name="BusinessFault">
        <soap:fault name="BusinessFault" use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:fault>
    <wsdl:fault name="ServiceFault">
        <soap:fault name="ServiceFault" use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
```

By default wsimport has generated service method with Synonyms class as return type rather than GetSynonymResponse class.

My question is whether this is customizable  - is there a possibility to make wsimport  generate service methods with different signatures, particularly having GetSynonymResponse class as return type?

Thanks in advance,

Valery

Answer (score 2):

Found how this is configurable:

The feature called "WrapperStyle" should be disabled to make generated method return xxxResponse type.
This is accomplishable by providing -b parameter to wsimport like

> wsimport" -b binding.xml  ContactService.wsdl

with binding.xml contents as

```
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="ContactService.wsdl"
                                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                                xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
                                xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
                    <!-- Turn off wrapper style Java method signature generation -->
                    <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
</jaxws:bindings>
```